# "Currently On Air" for a Radio Website

Tags: javascript, timer, message

I'm trying to create the "Currently On Air" part of a radio website using JS and am currently stuck. So far I've got:

```
if (now.getDay() == monday && now.getHours() < 12.15) {
    dtString = "Non-Stop Music";
}
else if (now.getDay() == monday && now.getHours() < 13) {
    dtString = "More Great music";
```

If I remove the "now.getDay" part it will work but I need each day to be unique.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean that each day needs to be unique? As in, each day has a different message depending if it's during a radio show?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is now is not a date? Are you creating now like this:

```
var now = new Date();
```

Also, getDay returns a number not a string. Monday = 1

So `now.getDay() == 1` is what you want.
I don't think getHours will return a decimal. It will be either 12 or 13, not 12.15 or anything like that. You will need to use get minuets in combination of get hours if you want to check against fractions of an hour.

Read the javascript date specifications and see what data you can expect to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

getDay() returns an integer.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

What is "monday"?

0 = Sunday,
1 = Monday,
etc

Comment: Please don't point people to w3schools. Please use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) or... pretty much anywhere else.

Comment: Why? It has the information he needs.  Why does it matter where I link?

Comment: People hate W3 on here. They have a internal goal to steer people clear of W3. Advising people to remove them from their search results etc. Just don't bother.

Comment: Because w3schools perperuates incorrect information that is damaging to the overall quality of software development on the web. See http://w3fools.com/

Comment: So that link I posted has incorrect information?  Please tell me what was incorrect on there.

Comment: Nope... it's not... their example on the provided link is a prime example of the low quality of this site. Their example will be incorrect on 6 out of 7 days that anyone tries it (ie any day that isn't a Monday).

Comment: I thought the point of stack overflow was to educate.  If I'm posting incorrect information then I welcome any downvotes, but the fact is that link has valid information.

Comment: Alright alright alright, you win.  I updated my post.  Geeeez

Comment: "Their example will be incorrect on 6 out of 7 days that anyone tries it (ie any day that isn't a Monday)." No it won't. It's showing Monday because today is Monday.

Answer (score 0):

[`now.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns an integer for current day. So, for monday you'd want to check that now.getDay() returns 1.

For example, if I were to implement this on your code

```
if (now.getDay() == 1 && now.getHours() < 12.15) {
    dtString = "Non-Stop Music";
}
```

Comment: +0: getDay() is right, but getHours() returns an integer, so 12.15 doesn't do much. You'd need to use getMinutes() as well

Comment: Since the question was only about `getDay()`, that's what I'm focusing on.